# reading multiple files contained in a zip file with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, zip

I have multiple zip files containing different types of txt files. 
Like below:

```
zip1 
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
```

How can I use pandas to read in each of those files without extracting them?

I know if they were 1 file per zip I could use the compression method with read_csv like below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(textfile.zip, compression='zip')
```

Any help on how to do this would be great.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible without extracting them...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can pass `ZipFile.open()` to `pandas.read_csv()` to construct a `pandas.DataFrame` from a csv-file packed into a multi-file `zip`.

#### Code:

```
pd.read_csv(zip_file.open('file3.txt'))
```

#### Example to read all `.csv` into a dict:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_file = ZipFile('textfile.zip')
dfs = {text_file.filename: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(text_file.filename))
       for text_file in zip_file.infolist()
       if text_file.filename.endswith('.csv')}
```

Comment: What if I have the url of the `zipfile`? It only works if I have it in my local machine!

Comment: @Farid Alijani True, Please help in case of ZipFile url

Comment: @FaridAlijani, @nitinkhatri789, it is generally a bad idea to download an entire dataset each time you run your code. Most of the time it is better to download manually the zip file, and access it locally. If you really need to, you can still use `urllib.request.url_retrieve`.

Answer (score 8):

The most simplest way to handle this (if you have multiple parts of one big csv file compressed to a one zip file).

```py
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(ZipFile('some.zip').open(i)) for i in ZipFile('some.zip').namelist()],
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with XML files awhile ago. The zipfile module can get you there.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

z = ZipFile(yourfile)

text_files = z.infolist()

for text_file in text_files:
    z.read(text_file.filename)
```

If you want to concatenate them into a pandas object then it might get a bit more complex, but that should get you started. Note that the `read` method returns bytes, so you may have to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have empty txt files in the zipfile:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
z = ZipFile('textfile.zip')
df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(z.open(i.filename)) for i in z.infolist() if i.compress_size > 0],
    ignore_index=True)
```

Otherwise, the "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file" would show up.