# read_csv one file from several files in a gzip?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gzip

I have several files in my tar.gz zip file. I want to read only one of them into a pandas data frame. Is there any way to do that?
Pandas can read a file inside a gz. But seems like there is no way to tell it specifically read one of them if there are several files inside the gz.

Would appreciate any thoughts.
Babak

Comment: That can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575251/reading-multiple-files-contained-in-a-zip-file-with-pandas

Answer (score 2):

To read a specific file in any compressed folder we just need to give its name or position for e.g to read a specific csv file in a zipped folder we can just open that file and read the content.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 
import pandas as pd 
# opening the zip file in READ mode 
with ZipFile("results.zip") as z:
    read = pd.read_csv(z.open(z.infolist()[2].filename))
    print(read)
```

Here the folder structure of results looks like and I want to read test.csv :

```
$ data_description.txt sample_submission.csv test.csv train.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I had to use tarfile library cause Zipfile can not handle tar.gz files

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pardata](https://pardata.readthedocs.io/), you can do this in one line:

```
import pardata

data = pardata.load_dataset_from_location('path-to-zip.zip')['table/csv']
```

The returned `data` variable should be a dictionary of all csv files in the zip archive.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the main co-authors of pardata.