# Working with multiple ZIP files inside directory and convert, rename the files with Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, rename

I have directory that have a lot of ZIP files. The ZIP files contain a lot of CSV files. First, I want to change the format of CSV files into parquet. Second, I need to rename all the parquet files and store the data into CSV. (Code below). I need to work with the zip files and not extracting the files to save some storage space.

Below is the code to convert to .parquet.

```
flist = ul.get_flist(r"D:\Proyekan\Data yang udah di extract", "csv")
target_folder = "D:\\Proyekan\\Data yang udah di extract\\Parquet\\"
for i, fpath in enumerate(flist):
    #fname = fpath.split('\\')[-1]
    df = pd.read_csv(fpath)
    fname = fpath.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0] + '.parquet'
    print(f"{i:03} ... Working on file ... {fname}")
    df.to_parquet(f"{target_folder}{fname}", compression="gzip")
```

And below is the code to rename the files

```
import os
import pandas as pd
#This is to rename files

path = "D:\Proyekan\Data FDM"
count = 1

ori_filename = []
new_filename = []
folder = []
head, tail = os.path.split(path)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        new_filecode = "flight_" + str(1000000 + count) +".mat"

        ori_filename.append(os.path.basename(file))
        new_filename.append(new_filecode)
        folder.append(os.path.basename(root))

        fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
        os.rename(fullpath, os.path.join(root, new_filecode))

        count += 1

#Store data to csv
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ori_filename, new_filename, folder)), columns = ['raw_file','file_id','tail_number'])
df.to_csv(r'D:\Proyekan\FILES\Metadata.csv',index = False, header = True)
```

Any ideas how do I edit this code to read ZIP files? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: bear with me. which comes first? IIUC, u want to read the csv files in the zip files, then convert to parquet. so zip -> csv -. parquet? or r they separate tasks?

Comment: yes exactly like this, if I can, i want to make it in 1 tasks.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575940/7175713) and see if it helps

Comment: sorry I don't think it would help because it only reads 1 zip @sammywemmy

Answer (score 0):

this is a shot in the dark, try it and let's see how it goes:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
folder = 'list of zipped files'
#iterate through every zip file
for zips in folder:
    with ZipFile(zips) as myzip:
        for csv in myzip.namelist():
            with myzip.open(csv) as myfile:
                #read the csv in the zip and convert to parquet
                #if this does not work, u could break down the steps
                #read the data first into a variable, then to parquet next
                pd.read_csv(myfile).to_parquet('new_location')
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D' got this error. alr make sure the directory is right.