# Read the contents of text file into a pandas dataframe from a zip folder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a zip file and inside the zip file, I have a series of folders that in turn contains text files. Like below.

```
  zip1 
     - folder 1
       - folder x
         - file1.txt
         - file2.txt
       - folder y
         - file3.txt
         - file4.txt
       - folder z
         - file6.txt
         - file7.txt
     - folder 2
       - folder m
         - file9.txt
         - file10.txt
       - folder n
         - file11.txt
         - file12.txt
```

I tried to extract the contents of the text file using pandas, based on the [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575940/3046211), however with no luck. The zip file is present in the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uvdaK_YhRc42HIjYSWNPpJLoiVIvYMby/view?usp=share_link).

I also tried to extract the text file contents using the below, but again without luck.

```
df = pd.read_csv(textfile.zip, compression='zip')
```

I would like to extract the contents of the text file present in a zip file to a pandas data frame and then to a csv, but the question is how can I extract the contents of a text file to a pandas data frame from a zip file without having to extract the zip file explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [**`ZipFile.infolist()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) to return the zip_path/name of each file contained in the `.zip`, then create a dictionnary of dataframes (a dataframe for each `.txt`) and finally make a [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to have a single big dataframe.

Try this:

```
import pandas
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_file = ZipFile(r"C:\Users\abokey\Downloads\data_new.zip")

dico_dfs_txt = {}

for file in zip_file.infolist():
    if file.filename.endswith(".txt"):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(file.filename), header=None)
        temp_df.insert(0, "filename", file.filename)
        dico_dfs_txt[file.filename] = temp_df
        
out= pd.concat(dico_dfs_txt, ignore_index=True)

display(out.head())
```

##### # Output :

[image]

If needed, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save the amount of data you need as a csv.